# What’s wrong with this proof that $5$ is prime?

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations, quantifiers

I’m reading *How To Prove It* and I’m confused as to how the proof of “$x$ is prime” is correct.

I've written proof given below and also my conclusion after substituting in values for $x$, $y$ and $z$:

> $5$ is prime. We have
>   $$\stackrel{(x)}{5} = \stackrel{(y)}{1} \times \stackrel{(z)}{5}.$$ 
>   Logical form of $x$ is prime:
>   $$x > 1 \land \lnot \exists y\,\exists z\left(x=yz \land y < x \land z < x\right)$$
>   Plugging in values for $x$, $y$ and $z$:
>   $$5 > 1 \land \lnot \exists1\,\exists 5 \left(5=1\times 5 \land 1 < 5 \land \boldsymbol{5 < 1}\right)$$
>   But $5<1$ is false.

My conclusion is that $5 < 1$ is false. What’s wrong?

Comment: that's why the "not" is there. There is no y,z that meets the conditions.

Comment: You need to give an accurate quotation from the book for your question to be answerable.

Comment: @alexwlchan thanks for edit, how did you write the math symbols ?

Comment: @blue-sky I used MathJax. There's a basic tutorial here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and if you need to look up a particular symbol, you can use DeTexify: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to prove $\neg \exists y\, (\cdots)$, you can't just pick *one* value for $y$ and plug that in. That's how you prove $\exists y\, (\cdots)$, but the negation changes everything.

What you need to prove is that one *can't pick any* value for $y$ that makes the "$(\cdots)$" true, or in other words that *every possible* value for $y$ makes the "$(\cdots)$" *false*.

What you show here is just that there is *one* value for $y$ (and $z$) that makes the rest false -- not that every *other* value makes it false too.

---

Concretely, you want to prove $$\neg\exists y\exists z\,(5=yz \land y < 5 \land z < 5)$$
which is the same as
$$\forall y \forall z \, \neg(5=yz \land y < 5 \land z < 5)$$
which is the same as
$$\forall y \forall z \, (5\ne yz \lor y \ge 5 \lor z \ge 5)$$

Answer (score 1):

Not quite correct. You cannot just plug in two values for $y$ and $z$ and conclude the proof. You need to go through *all* combinations of possible $y$ and $z$.

Now, a positive integer $x$ is prime if and only if whenever $x$ is expressed as a product of positive integers: $x=yz$, one of $y$ and $z$ must equal $x$. (You can tweak this definition to admit negative primes and negative $y$ and $z$ if your wish.) This is the same as what your wrote, but turned on its head.

Since one of your requirements is here that $1<y<5$ and $1<z<5$, there are 3 possibilities for each: 2, 3 and 4. Checking these products, we see that none equal 5. Therefore 5 is prime.

Let me throw in a caution. In writing mathematics, you should strive for **readability**. Expressing properties as long strings of logical symbols is not a very good way to write mathematics, since it requires considerably greater effort to read.

Comment: "In writing mathematics, you should strive for readability. Expressing properties as long strings of logical symbols is not a very good way to write mathematics, since it requires considerably greater effort to read." the logical form I posted is a copy of what is given in book "How To Prove It" . What is a more readable representation ?

Comment: I will not comment on Velleman's book, but a better representation would be. "An integer greater than one is prime if it cannot be expressed as a product of two strictly smaller integers".

Comment: ok, I think book representation is used to explain logic quantifiers but I agree English description is more understandable :)

Comment: My view on logical notation is that you should know it, but avoid it whenever possible. =)

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of your logical form is that, any prime means a natural number greater than one AND it cannot be expressed as a product of two numbers which are less than itself. For example, in your case, 5 is prime since 5>1 AND the only product of two numbers equal to 5 that you can find out is $5*1$. In other words, if $5=xy$, then $x\ge 5$ or $y\ge5$.